# How to test whether covariates are significant with "xreg=" and "auto.arima()" (Error message)

Tags: r, time-series, arima, predictor, error-message

I have 10 separate time series with one response variable (#users) and 4 predictor (dummy) variables (discount, feature_update, non_feature_update, bugfix).  One exemplary time series looks like this:

```
date;max_players;discount;feature_update;non_feature_update;bugfix
    2016-08-25;550787;0;0;0;0
    2016-08-26;544806;0;0;0;0
    2016-08-27;536004;0;0;0;0
    2016-08-28;546000;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-01;515410;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-02;515410;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-03;557799;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-04;573314;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-05;574341;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-06;572226;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-07;530141;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-08;544146;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-09;525664;0;0;1;0
    2016-09-10;571421;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-11;600316;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-12;596331;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-13;539819;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-14;528193;0;0;0;1
    2016-09-15;530805;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-16;530380;0;0;1;0
    2016-09-17;588619;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-18;638360;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-19;637515;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-20;564818;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-21;558376;0;0;1;0
    2016-09-22;553994;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-23;555269;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-24;601253;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-25;613028;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-26;609126;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-27;540141;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-28;538047;0;0;1;0
    2016-09-29;544434;0;0;0;0
    2016-09-30;548141;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-01;590230;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-02;613097;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-03;598950;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-04;559436;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-05;552031;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-06;556320;0;1;0;0
    2016-10-07;554221;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-09;646334;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-10;628981;0;0;1;0
    2016-10-11;584079;0;0;1;0
    2016-10-12;573494;0;0;1;0
    2016-10-13;590436;0;0;1;0
    2016-10-14;584281;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-15;632559;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-16;661985;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-17;646283;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-18;565030;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-19;552751;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-20;564004;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-21;561903;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-22;623083;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-23;647299;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-24;624196;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-25;564167;0;0;1;0
    2016-10-26;548445;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-27;543803;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-28;550837;0;0;0;1
    2016-10-29;591304;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-30;612910;0;0;0;0
    2016-10-31;613226;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-04;596301;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-05;599240;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-06;627124;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-07;611584;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-08;532334;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-09;539366;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-10;526953;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-11;539705;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-12;598838;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-13;626360;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-14;609295;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-15;541529;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-16;546602;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-17;529147;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-18;528129;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-19;595119;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-20;617652;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-21;601809;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-22;541586;0;0;0;0
    2016-11-23;547539;1;0;0;0
    2016-11-24;555683;1;0;0;0
    2016-11-25;558932;1;0;0;0
    2016-11-26;611117;1;0;0;0
    2016-11-27;625876;1;0;0;0
    2016-11-28;608906;1;1;0;0
    2016-11-29;540550;1;0;0;1
    2016-11-30;578490;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-01;575494;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-02;574372;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-03;632999;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-04;662460;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-05;637935;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-06;562748;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-07;569392;0;0;1;0
    2016-12-08;567637;0;0;1;0
    2016-12-09;521844;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-10;575434;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-11;603615;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-12;582266;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-13;515906;0;1;0;0
    2016-12-14;510000;0;0;0;1
    2016-12-15;512679;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-16;513677;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-17;558715;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-18;586213;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-19;567955;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-20;549755;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-21;548122;0;0;0;0
    2016-12-22;557662;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-23;556800;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-24;556800;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-25;556800;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-26;556800;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-27;556800;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-28;464514;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-29;600307;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-30;608579;1;0;0;0
    2016-12-31;617489;1;0;0;0
    2017-01-01;527325;1;0;0;0
    2017-01-02;586605;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-03;533340;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-04;615247;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-05;614587;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-06;620470;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-07;652854;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-08;672549;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-09;658198;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-10;590818;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-11;593498;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-12;583741;0;0;1;0
    2017-01-13;592038;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-14;643886;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-15;688978;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-16;663907;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-17;640165;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-18;614374;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-21;654320;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-22;682619;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-23;792739;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-24;730879;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-25;707397;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-26;720396;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-27;684720;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-28;735876;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-29;786654;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-30;814616;0;0;0;0
    2017-01-31;701556;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-02;681715;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-03;679929;0;0;1;0
    2017-02-04;704161;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-05;742866;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-06;723039;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-07;652628;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-08;645809;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-10;663594;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-11;705889;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-12;744468;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-13;734782;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-14;649498;0;0;1;0
    2017-02-15;608329;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-16;631995;0;0;0;1
    2017-02-17;632130;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-18;692524;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-19;704709;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-20;714208;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-21;673810;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-22;651005;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-23;669172;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-24;633032;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-25;686376;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-26;716121;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-27;691565;0;0;0;0
    2017-02-28;628780;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-01;638415;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-02;626142;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-03;613269;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-04;686031;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-05;715449;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-06;670904;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-07;615829;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-08;657426;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-09;621064;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-10;610761;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-11;680655;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-12;717597;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-13;702023;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-14;620293;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-15;623902;0;0;1;0
    2017-03-16;617890;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-17;672521;0;0;1;0
    2017-03-18;723042;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-19;742356;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-20;736773;0;0;0;1
    2017-03-22;632408;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-23;644436;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-24;632808;0;0;1;0
    2017-03-25;707789;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-26;718526;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-27;726242;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-28;646662;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-29;628450;0;1;0;0
    2017-03-30;635783;0;0;0;0
    2017-03-31;634066;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-01;691424;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-02;709841;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-03;685747;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-04;610638;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-05;591525;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-06;603084;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-07;606153;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-08;671237;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-09;695028;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-10;653292;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-11;623083;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-12;611705;0;0;1;0
    2017-04-13;621878;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-14;632507;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-15;678017;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-16;662140;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-17;643858;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-18;648328;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-19;622811;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-20;619212;0;0;1;0
    2017-04-21;626863;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-22;695991;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-23;708468;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-24;678710;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-25;604982;0;0;1;0
    2017-04-26;596141;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-27;583886;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-28;588990;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-29;656297;0;0;0;0
    2017-04-30;657033;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-01;658518;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-02;624256;0;0;0;1
    2017-05-03;580736;0;0;0;1
    2017-05-04;581236;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-05;571557;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-06;625281;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-07;646923;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-08;651658;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-09;602298;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-10;581682;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-11;574345;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-12;572559;0;0;1;0
    2017-05-13;629636;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-14;637449;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-15;598319;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-16;545741;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-17;543021;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-18;531927;0;0;1;0
    2017-05-19;552581;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-20;584163;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-21;609379;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-22;589513;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-23;546107;0;0;1;0
    2017-05-24;558359;0;0;0;1
    2017-05-25;692966;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-26;648271;0;0;0;1
    2017-05-27;644099;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-28;634579;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-29;658696;0;0;0;0
    2017-05-30;623180;0;0;0;1
    2017-05-31;596527;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-01;610675;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-02;587333;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-03;594458;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-04;596892;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-05;614621;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-06;607887;0;0;0;1
    2017-06-07;589592;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-08;588571;0;0;0;1
    2017-06-10;559019;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-11;550924;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-12;568688;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-13;559171;0;1;0;0
    2017-06-14;556769;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-15;553916;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-16;569006;0;1;0;0
    2017-06-17;547096;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-18;542343;0;0;0;0
    2017-06-19;560055;0;0;0;1
    2017-06-20;540780;0;0;0;1
    2017-06-23;534468;1;0;0;0
    2017-06-24;512874;1;0;0;0
    2017-06-25;511465;1;0;0;0
    2017-06-26;553576;1;0;0;0
    2017-06-27;552073;1;0;0;1
    2017-06-28;546514;1;0;0;0
    2017-06-29;543096;1;0;0;0
    2017-06-30;537716;1;0;0;0
```

Due to a previous [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291384/which-model-to-considerate-to-analyse-the-impact-of-4-predictor-variables-on-a-t) you helped me to understand that I should build a regression with arma errors "https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/" or a transfer function model. My goal is to make a statement whether one of the exogenous dummy variables has an significant impact on the time series or not.

I started to work on a R script that is inspired by [How to setup xreg argument in auto.arima() in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41070/how-to-setup-xreg-argument-in-auto-arima-in-r). I use `auto.arima()` to approx. a model of the series by including the `xreg=` argument. `xreg=` contains a matrix of the exogenous variables.

The script looks as follows:

```
#load forecast package
library(forecast)

#load one dataset per game ("g")
g <- read.csv("C:[...].csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

#generate time series objects for "number of users" and predictor variables

user = ts(g$max_players) #y

discount <- ts(g$discount) #x1

feature_update <- ts(g$feature_update) #x2

non_feature_update <- ts(g$non_feature_update) #x3

bugfix <- ts(g$bugfix) #x4

#build a matrix "X" containing "xi"

X <- matrix(c(discount, feature_update, non_feature_update, bugfix), nrow = length(discount))


#check "user" for seasonality by generating ACF and PACF graph

tsdisplay(user, main = "User TS (Observed)")

#generate auto.arima model and take seasonality into account.

user_mod <- auto.arima(user, seasonal = TRUE, xreg = X)

#print model description
user_mod

#visualize observed and model values

plot(user, col = "red", type = "p", main = "Model vs. Actual")
lines(fitted(user_mod))

#check residuals

tsdiag(user_mod, gof.lag = 20) #make sure that Ljung-Box p-value is bigger than 95% conf+
                                #make sure that ACF residuals are within 95% conf.

#apply Ljung-Box Test to the residuals for 50 lags
Box.test(user_mod$residuals, lag = 50, type = "Ljung-Box")
```

I tested the script for 5 of my ts which always resulted in the same error:

> Error in auto.arima(user, seasonal = TRUE, xreg = X) : 
>     No suitable ARIMA model found

My questions are:

1. Is the error caused by a mistake in the script (technical), a misunderstanding of the concept (theory) or does the error mean that there is no significant impact of x on y.
2. How could I alter the script to come to a solution that shows for each x whether it is significant or not?

Comment: You could dig into the source code of `auto.arima` to see what sequence of events produces the error message. Just type `auto.arima` in R console and hit "Enter" to get the source code. I was able to find the error message this way, but it takes some time reading and understanding the code that leads to the message...

Comment: Probably caused by rank-deficient regressors. The latest github version now checks for this problem and returns a more informative error message.

Comment: Dear @RobHyndman, it might be a bit off topic but I read through your blogpost "The ARIMAX model muddle". As a result I try to apply the idea of "regression with ARIMA errors" on the model posted above. Is it correct to build a matrix of the exogenous (dummy) variables and to use this matrix as value for xreg= ?

Comment: It looks ok, but check the rank of the xreg matrix. svd(X)$d should have no near-zero values.

Comment: @RobHyndman, thanks for your advice! My final question concerns the coefficients of the exogenous variables.  You wrote in your blogpost that they can be interpreted like the coefficients of an ordinary regression. Can I judge their significance with the usual p-value?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was able to solve the issue by adding the `nrow=` and `ncol=` parameter to the `matix()` function. The rows need to have the lenght of the ts and each exogenous variable equals one column:

```
X <- matrix(c(discount, feature_update, non_feature_update, bugfix), nrow = 295, ncol = 4)
```

This change in combination with `colrename()` led to the following exemplary result for `auto.arima( [...], xreg = X)`:

```
Series: user 
Regression with ARIMA(5,1,0) errors 

Coefficients:
          ar1      ar2      ar3      ar4      ar5   discount  feature_update  non_feature     bugfix
      -0.0548  -0.5245  -0.3129  -0.2969  -0.4131  -368.7454       -447.6808    -104.3459  -172.6037
s.e.   0.0532   0.0513   0.0562   0.0510   0.0538  1126.3988        676.8783     584.7867   636.2311

sigma^2 estimated as 28067576:  log likelihood=-2934.58
AIC=5889.16   AICc=5889.94   BIC=5926

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 240.7161 5207.315 3833.528 -0.1999951 6.955508 0.7603703 0.01612563
```

Regardless of the result's quality I get the covariates as part of the model.